# Content URL - Sony camera API

Tags: sony-camera-api

I have problem with downloading image file using url returned by "getContentList" using Sony Camera API.

After decoded url I've got smth as below:

http://192.168.122.1:8080/contentstransfer/orgjpeg/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000003-0000092B_3_1_1000

However documentation points out only to download it using "Http Get".

> "There are URLs for original still image or movie, resized data and
>   thumbnails in the content information. The client can download images
>   from camera via HTTP GET request."

I've got 500 error and I'm stuct with it.

I've tried to download it on "remote shooting" mode and on "contents transfer" but no luck (500 error).

If anyone has any clue I will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you need to decode the url. I develop an open-source Swift library for remote control of Sony cameras and I don’t do anything with the url, simply use URLSession to download it!

Full error message might help too!